# Philips Hue c#/json/http

Tags: c#, json

So I'm working off another tutorial... `request.GetRequestStreamAsync() should be request.GetRequestStream()` (According to the tutorial)<-- Meaning that's what they show, but that's just causes an error. `.getRequestStream()` is not a known function in Visual Studio.

I'm trying to send a json message to the Philips hue bridge. In this case it's a "PUT" but it could be anything.

Literally just started json and barely know c#, sorry if this is super basic.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //HELLLLLLLOOOOO
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.3/api/139f12ce32a30c473368dbe25f6586b/lights/1/state");
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "PUT";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
    {
        string json = "{\"on\":\false}";
        streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding Question and more details: 

I'm getting the following error: 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStream' 

So am I missing a reference?

I have System.Net as a reference already.

Comment: Also, I'm doing this as a windows universal app, I don't know if that makes a difference. 

Thanks for any input

Comment: It turns out Universal Window Apps do not support 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest' @VictorProcure After some more searching I think I need to use System.Net.Requests to do what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No question in your post, but.

```
.getRequestStream() is not a known function in Visual Studio.
```

It isn't, but request.**G**etRequestStream() is!

Which you would use like this in the code:

```
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
    {

    }
```

If you want to use `GetRequestStreamAsync()`:

```
   using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
    {

    }
```

But your method must have the `async` keyword. And since you're calling `GetRequestStreamAsync()` from an override, and you can't override a non-async method and make it async, you basically can't do `GetRequestStreamAsync()` from that method (unless you call another method that is `async` from it).

Comment: request.GetRequestStream is what's not working for me. Like I don't have the right reference. But GetRequestStreamAsync is a valid reference - but as you pointed out, also won't work for what I'm trying to do. 

Thanks for the input

Comment: I did some more reading into what async actually did and was successful in getting it to work. I also realized that System.Net.Http has all the methods I need, and that System. Net.Http.Webrequests are not available in universal windows apps, that's why I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming its not working or getting an error. Since you really didn't ask a question, but you can try putting your JSON sends/receives into a try/catch. To catch the WebException that is coming back.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.3/api/139f12ce32a30c473368dbe25f6586b/lights/1/state");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
try {
   using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
    {
        string json = "{\"on\":\false}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
catch (WebException)
{ 
    //error handling
}
```

Edit: Make sure you have references to:

- System.Net
- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Http.WebRequest

Comment: Thanks for the input, the try/catch just jumps over the .GetRequestStream because it's an invalid reference. That's my mistake for not specifying.

Comment: I've updated with the references that I needed to add to make it work

Comment: Ok so System.Net.Http.WebRequest is not valid. I would have thought that using System.Net would reference everything below. 

So do I have to update my System.Net reference or something? I can't find anywhere to download a reference and import it. Again - Super new to C# so I'm in the woods here.

Comment: Add the reference, under the references location in visual studio. Right Click References -> Add Reference. Should be under assemblies